# I want to get this array to get printed and not the php code because I'm not sure if it's my code

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to be able to print the array in those orders and not post the php file after I press submit.
[Html code and the output[Php code and the output[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLpD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUZ06.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gJs3.png)
array.php code

```
 <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "post") {
    // Retrieve the inputted values
    $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
    $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
    $value3 = $_POST['value3'];
    $value4 = $_POST['value4'];
    $value5 = $_POST['value5'];
    $value6 = $_POST['value6'];
    $value7 = $_POST['value7'];
    $value8 = $_POST['value8'];

    // Store the inputted values in an array
    $array = array($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5, $value6, $value7, $value8);

      // Output the original array (with and without keys)
      echo "<h3>Original Array</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);

      // Delete two elements from the array
      array_splice($array, 2, 2);
      echo "<h3>Array After Deleting Two Elements</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);

      // Remove gaps from the array
      $values = array_values($array);
      echo "<h3>Array After Removing Gaps</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);

      // Sort the array in ascending order (with and without keys)
      sort($values);
      echo "<h3>Array Sorted in Ascending Order</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $values) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($values);

      // Sort the array in descending order (with and without keys)
      rsort($array);
      echo "<h3>Array Sorted in Descending Order</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);

      // Sort the array in ascending order according to values (with and without keys)
      asort($array);
      echo "<h3>Array Sorted in Ascending Order (by Values)</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);

      // Sort the array in ascending order according to keys (with and without keys)
      ksort($values);
      echo "<h3>Array Sorted in Ascending Order (by Keys)</h3>";
      echo "Without Keys/Indexes: " . implode(", ", $array) . "<br>";
      echo "With Keys/Indexes: ";
      print_r($array);
      }
  ?>
```

index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <head>
      <title>HTML Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form  action="array.php" method="post">
        <label for="value1">Value 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"><br><br>

        <label for="value2">Value 2:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"><br><br>

        <label for="value3">Value 3:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value3" id="value3"><br><br>

        <label for="value4">Value 4:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value4" id="value4"><br><br>

        <label for="value5">Value 5:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value5" id="value5"><br><br>

        <label for="value6">Value 6:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value6" id="value6"><br><br>

        <label for="value7">Value 7:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value7" id="value7"><br><br>

        <label for="value8">Value 8:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value8" id="value8"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried what I showed you above and tried many other ways as well.